# does not contain a default export - however it does

Tags: reactjs, typescript, recoiljs

This is a strange one, but could be missing something obvious? I have a Typescript Model setup which clearly declares an `export default`:

```
interface SeasonModel {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  startDate: string;
  endDate: string;
  isCurrentSeason: boolean;
  appUserId: string;
}

export default SeasonModel;
```

And I have it imported into several React components with no problems using:

```
import SeasonModel from "../../models/season-model";
```

However, when I try to import it into my Recoil Atom TS file (with the same import as above) I get the error:

> ./src/atoms/seasonAtoms.js Attempted import error:
> '../models/season-model' does not contain a default export (imported
> as 'SeasonModel').

Note that the wording of the error message suggests it has found the file, it just cannot see that there is a `default export` already on there.

I am really quite new to Recoil but do not understand how the import is fine on my other components but on when trying to import into this Recoil Atom?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You typically don't export types as default exports. I didn't even know that was allowed. I would recommend `export interface SeasonModel {}` and `import { SeasonModel } from '../../myfile'`. This will also make it much easier for your IDE to auto import this type.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have just tried that but now when I try using the referenced model in my Atom I get the error: Attempted import error: 'SeasonModel' is not exported from '../models/season-model'. lol Feels like I am going round in circles!

Comment: For this particular issue, It was something silly.... The file containing the Atom was Javascript instead of Typescript! Maybe just delete this one!!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code. Try a different IDE or language surface plugin aside from atom typescript. That code is totally valid

Comment: Atom is dead, you should probably change to a different IDE

Comment: By Atom I meant a recoilJS Atom... It is state management.

Comment: https://recoiljs.org/docs/basic-tutorial/atoms/